# Qué tipo de dato debo usar para guardar la cantidad en Unidad y Kilogramos mysql

Tags: mysql

quisiera que me ayudaran o dieran consejo en lo siguiente:

estoy creando una una Tabla, esta tiene los siguientes campos (`IdProducto,Descripcion,Cantidad,Importe`).

En el Campo Idproducto,voy a guardar datos de tipo Entero,ya que los IdProducto serian (100,101,102..,etc)..osea algo como el autonumerico. INT

En el Campo Descripcion, guardaria el nombre del producto. VARCHAR

En el Campo Cantidad, aqui guardaria datos que tendria numeros enteros y tambien decimales, por que ingresaria cantidad en unidad ,cantidad en kilogramos o gramos.

En el Campo Importe, aqui en donde guardaria los precios por unidad o por kilogramo de los productos
ejemplo

```
codigo descripcion    cantidad   importe
100    gaseosa              5      1000
101    zanahoria         2.50      2500
102    papa           1000.21    300000
103    cafe x unidad       25      1500
```

Entonces, que tipo de datos me aconsejan usar para el campo cantidad ya que necesito ir descontando en unidad, kilos o en gramos dependiendo la cantidad que el cliente desea llevar.
utilice INT pero me redondea a entero las cantidades, tambien double pero al sumar cantidad y resta me daba un valor como este 20.10000000007
que tipo de datos debo aplicar ...,muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende los tipos números que quieras almacenar. Existen tres tipos de dato número en SQL con punto flotante que puedes usar.

**FLOAT**

Te permite almacenar datos con punto flotante de precisión aproximada, utilízalo para números pequeños que no requieran una precisión exacta. Debes especificar el número de dígitos enteros y el número de decimales de la forma `FLOAT(6,2)` esto te permitirá tener 4 números enteros y dos dígitos decimales como 1.34, 4563.11, etc.

**DOUBLE**

Al igual que Float te permite almacenar datos con punto flotante, la diferencia esta en que te permite almacenar números más grandes. Se usa de la misma manera que `FLOAT`

**DECIMAL**

También conocido como `NUMERIC` permite almacenar grandes números decimales de punto fijo, por tanto, los cálculos con este tipo DECIMAL son exactos. El número máximo de dígitos que almacena es de 65. Su uso es igual a los demás; Por ejemplo `DECIMAL(20,6)` quiere decir que tendrá 14 dígitos enteros y 4 dígitos decimales.

Comment: Pero, entonces ¿cuál debe usar? por que ya expuso que `double` le da problemas con la exactitud de los resultados

Comment: Claro, pero no especificó como hizo su declaración usando `double`. Yo le recomendaría utilizar `float` o `double` pero especificando los enteros y decimales.

Comment: gracias por responder el tipo de dato double lo utilice sin especificar enteros y decimales